# How do i View the existing query of report in iReport 3.0?

Tags: sql, jasper-reports, report, ireport

I have this *jrxml* of the report and want to edit the existing query of the report. How do i view the existing report's query using **iReport 3.0**? I hope you guys can help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the designer (with the report already opened) go to: ***Data -> Report Query***

[image]

Comment: Please, vote/mark the answer as correct if you did resolve :)

Comment: There is no data tab in my jasper studio. What am i missing here